# $\mathrm{Hash}(A\|B)$ where $B$ is known, $A$ is unknown. Would knowing $\mathrm{Hash}(A\|C)$ as well as $C$, speed up a brute force search for $A$

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack

Let's say $\mathrm{Hash}(A\|B)$ is a hash of two concatenated strings, $A$ and $B$.

Suppose I am trying to figure out $A$ from $\mathrm{Hash}(A\|B)$, I know $B$ but not $A$, I want to brute force to find $A$. Let's ignore practical reality for a moment.

If I also know $\mathrm{Hash}(A\|C)$, $\mathrm{Hash}(A\|D)$ etc, as well as $C$ and $D$ etc. can I use this info to reduce the time required in the brute force search?

Comment: What are the size of all?

Comment: A few hundred characters worth of dictionary words.

Comment: Please don't cross post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928486/338051 delete the other copy.

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your definition of a hash function.

In general hash functions don't guarantee, that they hide their input.
A general hash function gives you three properties:

- preimage resistance (given $y = H(x)$ it is hard to find $x^*$ such that $H(x^*) = H(x)$)
- second preimage resistance (given $y = H(x)$ it is hard to find $x^*$ such that $H(x^*) = H(x)$ and $x^* \neq x$)
- collision resistance (it is hard to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $H(x_1) = H(x_2)$)

None of these properties guarantee that the hash function doesn't reveal part of the input - i.e. there are hash functions that reveal $A$.

**However**, in practice you typically model hash functions as random oracles - for any input, the function yields a randomly chosen output.

In this case it is easy to show that it is hard to find $A$.

You might also want to take a look at length extension attacks, which are a way many hash functions deviate from a random oracle. However, these won't help you in finding $A$, they will however help you in finding (roughly) $H(A \| B \| C)$, given $H(A \| B)$ (without knowing $A$ or $B$).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll look into how length extension attacks can make my problem more feasible. In general I'm using the hash function more as a checksum. If I find there has been changes, how can I recreate the data knowing the hashes described in the question. Have you encountered any similar problems? It could save me a bunch of time to be pointed to the right source of information,

Comment: This is an answer, not a comment. Please do not ask additional questions within the comment section below any answer.

Answer (score 1):

First the obvious: for most common hashes, if $B$ is large (several blocks), and $C$ is empty or small, and $A$ is amenable to brute force search, it makes a difference if $\hat C=\text{Hash}(A\mathbin\|C)$ is known, because testing if a value $A'$ matches $\text{Hash}(A'\mathbin\|C)=\hat C$ requires hashing less material than testing if $\text{Hash}(A'\mathbin\|B)=\hat B$, where $\hat B=\text{Hash}(A\mathbin\|B)$.

It's possible to construct a function $F$ where additional knowledge of $\hat C=F(A\mathbin\|C)$ with $C\ne B$ and $|B|=|C|$ would considerably help finding $A$ given $\hat B=F(A\mathbin\|B)$. But we do not know that's the case for standard hashes like those of the [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family. And if their security goal is met, that's not the case for more modern hashes like those of the [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) family.

Independently, knowing $\text{Hash}(A\mathbin\|C)$ with $C\ne B$ gives an additional criteria to confirm that $A'$ found by brute force with $\text{Hash}(A'\mathbin\|B)=\text{Hash}(A\mathbin\|B)$ is indeed $A$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply, it was helpful. You're saying that knowing C and D etc. will help me know that A is the correct A and not another A that happens to resolve to the same value.

It seems your also saying that a hash function could be made to take advantage of knowing C and D etc. But standard hash functions likely do not have that property. Am I getting that right?

Comment: @Xhiggy: yes! Basically, for a good hash, the best strategy is to search for the value of A using the shortest B, C, D... available, because that minimizes the duration; then check.